# Precedence of postfix prefix ++ and binary & operators

Tags: c, operator-precedence, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I'm confused with the postfix and prefix operator precedence in C, any help and hints would help.

I'll paste my test code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (++a & 0x01) // prefix version
   // if (a++ & 0x01) // postfix version
   {
      printf("++ first\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("& first\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I can now understand that in the postfix version, although `postfix ++` has a greater precedence, `a++` would return `0` here to `&` with `0x01` and would increment `a`'s value after this expression.

But what I can't understand is why in the prefix version, why `++a` is first evaluated? the operator precedence table indicates that `prefix ++` and `&` has the same precedence, and in addition, their associativity is `right-to-left`. Doesn't this means `&` should be evaluated first?

**EDIT:**
the chart I'm using: [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Comment: What chart are you using? that is not correct `++` has higher precedence than binary `&`, see [here](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your precedence table again. I believe you may be getting confused with the unary address operator `&` and the binary bitwise-and operator `&`.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

With this interpretation, you increment `a` before applying the bitwise-and.

Answer (score 0):

For prefix/postfix:

++a  ->  (retrieve + increment), then use the value.

a++  ->  (retrieve), use the value, (increment)

Precedence:   This in this way:

((++a) & 0x01)  ,  both ( & and ++ ) are in different expression.

Hope it helps to some extent to understand.